# Как вывести пагинацию на статической главной странице?

Tags: wordpress

Доброго времени суток! С помощью плагина Types создал произвольный тип записи, у меня это "Туры". В настройках чтения стоит статическая главная страница, создал front-page.php скопировал туда весь код page.php, а в нужном месте добавил цикл вывода туров:

```
<?php
  $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
  $args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 6,
    'post_type' => 'turs',
    'paged' => $paged,
    'meta_query' => array(
      'relation' => 'OR',
      array(
        'key' => 'wpcf-hot_turs',
        'value' => '1'
      )
    )
  );
  $query = new WP_Query( $args );
  if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
      $query->the_post();
      get_template_part( 'template/content-turs', get_post_format() );
    }?>
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      <?php the_posts_navigation(); ?>
    </div>
  <?php } else {
    get_template_part( 'template/content', 'none' );
  }
  wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

6 туров вывелось, а вот пагинации нет, в чем может быть причина?
И еще может быть подскажите как делать формы фильтры для таких вот выводов произвольных записей, буду очень благодарен!

Answer (score 0):

Но ведь 6 туров - это 1 страница, не так ли? Пагинация не нужна. 
P.S. И используйте `the_posts_pagination();`, `the_posts_navigation();` выводит ссылки только на слудующий и предыдущий пост и используется при показе отдельной записи.

Comment: Туров +100500, а на одной странице должно быть 6, т.е. нужна пагинация, указанные вами функции я использую, в коде видно.

Comment: Посмотрите файл functions.php и стоит ли у вас плагин NaviPage или что то вроде того, забыл название. Пагинация на страницах может конфликтовать если стоит этот плагин и если используете пагинацию из коробки.